# PDO fetch array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de renombrar las claves de un array asociativo que viene dado por PDOStatement::fetch.
La sentencia que preparo y ejecuto en SQL no viene al caso en si (aunque si la requieren, puedo agregarla). El hecho es que le pido a mi base de datos varios registros a través de INNERs y en 3 tablas se repite la columna "id". Cuando quiero accesar a través del array que vuelve PDO surgen inconvenientes por los nombres de las claves, lo cual me dificulta mucho el desarrollo. He intentado especificar el modo del fetch a 'NUM' sin mayor éxito (por defecto, FETCH() establece el modo en FETCH_BOTH).
¿Habrá alguna forma de poder renombrar las claves del array?

Nota: He pensado en cambiar los nombres de las columnas, ya que en este momento son pocas, pero no creería que fuese una solución viable (ni muy inteligente).

He pensado también utilizar la función array_map() e ir desligando con unset, pero al ser un no nativo en php, no he obtenido buenos resultados.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Te genera algún error o solo no logras identificar los indices del array?

Comment: Los más simple es **usar alias para aquellas columnas que quieres que se llamen diferente, dándoles los nombres que quieres**, por ejemplo: **`SELECT t1.id, t2.id as id_tabla2, t3.id as id_tabla3...`**  , en vez de querer pasar por procedimientos más oscuros que además podrían tener impacto en el rendimiento e implicar manipulaciones que podrían provocar resultados inesperados.

Comment: @Andrés no es un error propiamente, sino más bien algo confuso el array: me devuleve un array asociativo de la forma: 
_array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "3" ["username"]=> string(7) "user" [1]=> string(7) "user" ["password"]=> string(6) "1234" }_
El hecho es que hay varias columnas con el nombre "id" y es allí donde se me complica.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu pronta respuesta.
Recién acabo de modificar los nombres de las tablas (utilizando _'user as u, image as i, person as p..._') por ejemplo y no tengo cambios relevantes: sigue devolviendo las mismas claves para el array. Si es que te refieres a los alias de las tablas.

Comment: No son los nombres de las tablas lo que tienes que modificar, sino **los nombres de las columnas**. Si en las tablas `t1`, `t2` y `t3`, hay una columna llamada `id`, cuando tú haces esto: `SELECT t1.id, 
       t2.id as id_tabla2, 
       t3.id as id_tabla3` **estás dando un nombre diferente a la columna `id` de las tablas `t2` y `t3`**, y los nombres que les des serán los que estarán en el array. O sea, que en el array, la columna `id` de la `t2` se llamará `id_tabla2` y la columna `id` de la `t3` se llamará `id_tabla3`.

Comment: Entiendo tu predicamento, lo maximo que podrias hacer es devolver la información si hubiera múltiples columnas con el mismo nombre, el valor al que hace referencia dicha clave será un array con todos los valores de la fila de tuviera ese nombre de columna. no se si para ti seria una solución.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente @Andrés, pero como bien dijo A. Cedano es el comportamiento que estaba necesitando. Muchas gracias a ambos por la prontitud de sus respuestas :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más simple sería:

### Para la consulta

Usar alias para aquellas columnas que quieres que se llamen diferente, dándoles los nombres que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t2.id as id_tabla2, 
       t3.id as id_tabla3...
```

El uso de aliases no significa que cambies los nombres de las columnas en tus tablas directamente, sino que para esa consulta en concreto le asignas un *apodo* a determinadas columnas. Precisamente los alias son usados para diferenciar columnas que se llaman igual, cuando varias tablas intervienen en la consulta. El nombre real permanece intacto, pero para **ese** resultado la columna adquiere un nombre distinto.

### En los resultados

Usar [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), que te devolverá un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.

Tendrás entonces un array cuyos nombres de clave serán:

```
id 
id_tabla2
id_tabla3 ...
```

Recurrir a otros procedimientos, aparte de que podría tener impacto en el rendimiento de la aplicación, podría producir resultados inesperados.

En cambio, un `SELECT` con aliases, te permitiría dar otro nombre a la columna sin tener que modificar la tabla en sí, lo cual podría producir errores, sobre todo si tienes consultas diseminadas por toda la aplicación.

Comment: Es justamente lo que estaba necesitando. Demoré un instante en probar el query completo (son unos cuantos inners con unas cuantas tablas en realidad). Acabo de hacer un var_dump del array y las claves son las que había especificado en el query. Te agradezco enormemente :).